# Gittins Index for a simple example

Tags: decision-theory

Everything I can find on the Gittins Index is extremely in depth and abstract with almost no examples. I have spent hours digging through academic papers, lecture notes, and Wikipedia sources. I understand the Gittins Index conceptually, but I would like to include it in program, so I need to know how to compute it (even if the algorithm has a complexity of n factorial).

Is there anyone who can actually solve a simple example like the one below?

This is a version of the classic multi-armed-bandit problem:
I'm at a casino, there are 3 machines M_1, M_2, M_3
Every machine pays out \$1 for a win, \$0 for a loss
I've played M_1 three times, it has 2 wins 1 loss
I've played M_2 four times, it has 2 wins 2 losses
I've played M_3 two times, it has 1 win 1 loss

If I discount future payouts by 50%; 
What is the Gittins Index of M_1? 
(An actual number in decimal form)
What steps do you take to get that number? 
(Pseudo code would be great)

Thanks for at least reading the problem

Comment: I have now asked my statistics professor, linear algebra professor, theoretical computer science professor, and a computer science faculty member all at Texas A&M and none of them had heard of the Gittins Index.

Answer (score 3):

Gittins indices are hard to compute.  This paper offers a good overview of various algorithms:
http://www.ece.mcgill.ca/~amahaj1/projects/bandits/book/2013-bandit-computations.pdf